# how to make PPPoE login from specific LAN?

Tags: windows-7, lan, pppoe

i am using windows 7 with 3 NICs  and i need to log in using PPPoE connection. i have 3  lease lines.my isp is using MAC security. i want to ask that how to make pppoe login from specific NIC and multiple PPPoe login is possible? if yes then how to do load balancing in win 7?( using win 7 ultimate.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that Windows PPPoE client automatically searches for PPPoE services to connect to on all NICs. If you don't set the service name in the PPPoE connection's property tab then the first one found will be the one connected to (assuming user and password authenticate).

Otherwise, ask your ISP(s) for their PPPoE service name(s) and configure the service name in the PPPoE client connection in Windows. In your case, you could create 3 different PPPoE connections, each with a different service name (assuming each ISP has a unique service name).

Theoretically you could be connected to all three simultaneously. As for load balancing, the only practical way of doing this, under Windows, is to analyse your traffic and set up specific routes. Not ideal.

Comment: Can we setup the ppoe connection via specific lan connection ?